# How can I join data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a search condition page.

What I want is that if multiple conditions are there search it as `&&` and if there is blank field, the search is not included blank field.

My current code is:

```
    name_sei = params[:nameSei]
    name_mei = params[:nameMei]
    email = params[:email]
    tel = params[:tel].to_i
    birth = params[:birth].to_i
    job_area = params[:jobArea]
    station = params[:station]
    sex = params[:sex]
    coordinator = params[:coordinator]
    inflow_souce = params[:inflowSouce]
    evaluation = params[:evaluation] || []
    skill = params[:skill] || []
    position = params[:position] || []

      users =
        User
          .order('users.created_at DESC')
          .includes(:evaluations, :skills, :positions)
          .where('name_sei like ?', "%#{name_sei}%" && 'name_mei like ?', "%#{name_mei}%" && 'email like ?', "%#{email}%"....)
```

The problem of my code is that if the field includes blank, rails would include `""` and search would fail.

So I came up this code:

```
      users =
        User
          .order('users.created_at DESC')
          .includes(:evaluations, :skills, :positions)
          .where('name_sei like ?', "%#{name_sei}%") if params[:nameSei] != ''

      users =
        User
          .order('users.created_at DESC')
          .includes(:evaluations, :skills, :positions)
          .where('name_mei like ?', "%#{name_mei}%") if params[:nameMei] != ''
```

I think if those two users data can join, it would be fine.

But I have no idea how I can join data.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Queries aren't finalized until they're run. You can do things like "users = User.where(...); users = users.where(...)".

Comment: Did you mean `users = User.order('users.created_at DESC').includes(:evaluations, :skills, :positions).where('name_sei like ?', "%#{name_sei}%") if params[:nameSei] != ''; users = User.order('users.created_at DESC').includes(:evaluations, :skills, :positions).where('name_mei like ?', "%#{name_mei}%") if params[:nameMei] != ''` works?

Comment: And if above is fine, how can I join?

Comment: This is a very common problem and there are tons of tutorials as well as gems that cover the problem. In general I would really recommend that you create a make class such as a virtual model that you can pass the search attributes into and which returns a an relation instead of making a fat controller. That will let you test it in isolation instead.

Comment: If you're in controll of the form I would also just change the input names so you don't have to do wonky stuff like `name_sei = params[:nameSei]`. Use snake_case **everywhere** except ClassNames and CONSTANTS.

Comment: thank you. Maybe I pretty don't understand. What you try to say is making class and defining relation? if you provide an example maybe I  understand well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "inlining" your search functionality in your controller move it out into a separate model:

```
# app/models/user_search.rb
# This is just a model to represent a search query
# its not actually saved to the database
class UserSearch
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  # @see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html
  attribute :name_sei
  attribute :name_mei
  attribute :tel,   :integer   
  attribute :birth, :integer   # Use a date instead?
  attribute :sex
  # ... define the rest of the attributes you want to be able to filter by

  # This just loops through the attributes of this model and 
  # filters the users based on it
  # blank attributes are filtered out
  # 
  # this will filter the results by using `WHERE x = y`
  # you can easily override it on a per attribute basis by 
  # implementing a `filter_by_x` method
  # that method should return a ActiveRecord::Relation or nil
  # @param [ActiveRecord::Relation] base
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation] the base scope with filters applied
  def to_scope(base: User.all)
    scopes = attributes.compact_blank do |attr, value|
      if respond_to?("filter_by_#{attr}")
        send("filter_by_#{attr}", value)
      else
        User.where(attr => value)
      end
    end
    scopes.compact.inject(base) {|memo, item| memo.merge(item)}
  end

  private

  def filter_by_name_sei(val)
    User.where('"users"."name_sei" like ?', "%#{val}%")
  end

  def filter_by_name_mei(val)
    User.where('"users"."name_mei" like ?', "%#{val}%")
  end
end
```

This lets you test it insolation by just passing a hash of search filters to the class instead of creating a whole HTTP request and then writing assertions about the response from the controller. You don't have to necissarily put this functionality into model - the key takeaway here is to not just plop it into your controller where it will be extremely hard to test.

Using a model does let you use all the goodness from ActiveModel though like typecasting, defaults, validations, I18n integration etc.

From your controller you can just use strong parameters to pass the parameters to the model:

```
class UsersController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users?search[name_sei]=foo...
  def index
    @search = UserSearch.new(search_parameters)
    @users = @search.to_scope(base: User.order(created_at: :desc))
  end

  private

  def search_parameters
    params.fetch(:search, {})
          .permit(
            :name_sei, :name_mei # ...
          )
  end
end
```

And you can just create a form thats bound to the model:

```
<%= form_with(model: @search, url: users_path, method: :get, scope: :search) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_sei %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_sei %>
  </div>

  # ...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For more complex search functionality I would look at gems like Ransack instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ohh... I absolutely didn't come up that idea... Bcz I've experienced rails for just a year haha. Thank you!! let me try your code. And I'll learn from your code. Thank's a lot!